# Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$. I want to show that $f$ is differentiable and compute the Jacobimatrix.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x_1,x_2)=x_1x_2$. I want to show that $f$ is differentiable and compute the Jacobimatrix.

My idea was the compute the Jacobimatrix so that the numerator is zero for all $x \rightarrow y$.

However, then $L(x-x_0) = (x_2, y_1) \cdot (x_1 - y_1, x_2 - y_2)$, where $x = (x_1, x_2), y = (y_1, y_2)$. But I cannot have the Jacobimatrix depend on $x$ ?

Can someone help me out ?

Comment: The jacobian matrix always is a certain matrix whose entries are all partial derivatives. Do you know this? If you do, what's keeping you from finding this matrix?

Comment: "My idea was the compute the Jacobimatrix so that the numerator is zero for all x→y". That doesn't make any sense. What is the definition of the Jacobimatrix? That should be a good start.

BTW, this is the first time I read Jacobimatrix (instead of Jacobian matrix). That's a cute name.

Comment: Also, for function $f:{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}$, the Jacobimatrix is just the gradient of $f$ (can you see why from the definitions?).

Answer (score 1):

Computing the partial derivatives we see:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1}(x_1,x_2)=x_2\;\;\;\;\;\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}(x_1,x_2)=x_1$$
Now since these partial derivatives exist and are continuous, $f$ is totally differentiable, with Jacobian matrix given by:

$$Df(x_1,x_2)=\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_2}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
x_2 & x_1
\end{pmatrix}$$

The Jacobian matrix may depend on $x$, because it is the representation of the linear map (the total derivative) $Df(x):\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ in a given point $x$.

Comment: How do I see that the fraction has limit 0, when using this Jacobian matrix in the formal definition of the derivative ?